# Preserve datatypes when using SQLite and QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql, spatialite

Following Nathan's SpatiaLite/DBManager solution in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44832/how-to-sum-up-values-of-neighbouring-polygons#answer-44839), I find that once the layer is loaded from DB Manager into QGIS (2.6.1), any calculated fields are appearing as text values instead of numeric types.  This is especially a problem because I would like to use those fields as the basis of style using graduated colors.

In the original table, the "pop" column is an integer datatype.  But when I look at the Layer Properties > Fields tab in QGIS, it clearly shows the field having type=QString, "Type name"=TEXT for these fields that were computed in the query, such as:

```
COALESCE(SUM(a2.pop),0) AS pop_neighbours
```

This seems to happen anytime there is a calculation in the SELECT statement, even for something as simple as:

```
a.pop + 1 AS pop1
```

I get the same result when trying to force the datatype:

```
CAST (a1.pop + 1 AS INTEGER) AS pop1
```

The datatype of any unmodified columns (such as a.pop) seems to be preserved without any problem.  The QGIS Layer Properties > Fields tab shows type=qlonglong, "Type name"=INTEGER.

Is there a way to preserve the datatypes of calculated fields?

## UPDATE:

For what it's worth, I see the same issue sometimes when using QSpatiaLite, depending on the method.  These work fine in QSpatiaLite:

- Create Table & Load in QGIS
- Create Spatial Table & Load in QGIS
- Create Spatial View & Load in QGIS

But these don't:

- Load in QGIS as Spatial Layer
- Create View & Load in QGIS
- "CREATE TABLE AS" within a query

Comment: Just a comment (I can't post comments 'cause not enough rep): I observe the same behaviour in 2.7.0-master (759a148). A little googling suggests this issue has existed from as far back as 2010(!) I'll file a qgis bug report when I get a chance...

Comment: @Ingo do you have a link to the 2010 mention?

Comment: This may be a bug, as reported here: [http://hub.qgis.org/issues/11809](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/11809)