# Find adjacent polygons and then sum values across all neighboring polygons

Tags: qgis, postgis

I'm working with a polygon layer that contains district level income data. For each individual district I would like to calculate the sum of the incomes from all neighboring districts. I found a post with SpatiaLite code that does what I want, but I was not able to adapt it to PostGIS ([Summing up values of neighbouring polygons using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44832/summing-up-values-of-neighbouring-polygons-using-qgis)).

The vector is called "example" and it is stored in a schema called "myschema". It contains three columns, "id, "income" and "name".

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Here's my latest attempt which is entirely based on the post I mentioned above:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(a2.income),0) as income_neighbours, 
        a1.income, 
        a1.name, 
        a1.id, 
        a1.geom 
FROM myschema.example a1
LEFT OUTER JOIN myschema.example a2 
             ON NOT a1.id = a2.id AND intersects(a2.geom, a1.geom)
GROUP BY a1.id
```

which returns this error:

SQL error: SELECT COALESCE(SUM(a2.income),0) as income_neighbours,              a1.income,              a1.name,              a1.id,              a1.geom  FROM myschema.example a1 LEFT OUTER JOIN myschema.example a2                   ON NOT a1.id = a2.id AND intersects(a2.geom, a1.geom) GROUP BY a1.id returned 0 [ERROR:  function intersects(geometry, geometry) does not exist
LINE 1: ...ple a2                   ON NOT a1.id = a2.id AND intersects...
^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
]

Comment: The error message is fairly clear -- You never defined the `a1` alias.

Comment: You seem to have copied that query 1:1, then replaced the table name - without specifying the **table alias** `a1`. Does your table actually have the listed columns, e.g. `pop` & `name`? You will also have to call `ST_Intersects` as `intersects` neither is a function nor an allowed shorthand in PostGIS.

Comment: You need a `from myschema.example a1`

Comment: did you add the postgis extension?

Comment: @IanTurton Yes, PostGIS is working.

Comment: @geozelot Thanks, after replacing intersects with ST_Intersects it works.

Comment: @IanTurton Thanks, I added that but there was another issue pointed out by geozelot. ST_intersects instead of intersects.